# JS: elegant way to wait for callbacks to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node app, I need to spawn multiple file writes and wait for them to finish before I proceed to other stuff. I've achieved that in the following way:

```
let counter = 0;
(some loop declaration) {
    // (preparing data etc)
    counter += 1;
    fs.writeFile(fname, fdata, (err) => {
        counter -= 1;
    });
}
let waitForCallbacks = function() {
    if (fcounter > 0) {
        setTimeout(waitForCallbacks, 0);
    }
};
waitForCallbacks();
```

While it works as desired, I feel that there could be some nicer idiom for that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Promises and `Promise.all`

Comment: const writeFileP = require('bluebird').promisify(fs.writeFile) ; // writeFileP(...) returns a promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> While it works as desired, I feel that there could be some nicer idiom for that.

This is one of the things promises are designed for. Here's that code rewritten with promises (and it could go further, there are libs to promise-ify NodeJS APIs):

```
let operations = []
(some loop declaration) {
    // (preparing data etc)
    operations.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(fname, fdata, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    }));
}
Promise.all(operations).then(() => {
    // All done
});
```

Or consider if we have a promise-ified version of `writeFile`:

```
let operations = []
(some loop declaration) {
    // (preparing data etc)
    operations.push(writeFileWithPromise(fname, fdata));
}
Promise.all(operations).then(() => {
    // All done
});
```

Or if the "loop" is over an iterable that we can turn into an array and use `map` on:

```
Promise.all(
    Array.from(theThingy).map(entry => writeFileWithPromise(entry.fname, entry.fdata))
).then(() => {
    // All done
});
```

Comment: @Benjamin: Thank you again! But the `Array.from` was necessary, because we needed to call `map` on the iterable (we aren't passing it directly into `Promise.all`).

Answer (score 3):

Promises is one way. However, if you're not fond of them, you can use a very well-known library called [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async).

Here's what you can do on your case. Here's what it would look like in a rudimentary manner using parallel processing:

```
async.parallel([
  function(done) {
    fs.writeFile(fname1, fdata1, (err) => {
      done(err, customResults1);
    });
  },
  function(done) {
    fs.writeFile(fname2, fdata2, (err) => {
      done(err, customResults2);
    });
  }
],
// The callback when every function above is done
function(err, results) {
  // `results` contains a collection of what you've passed
  // on the `done` callbacks above
});
```

To be more specific to your use case, it would look like:

```
async.parallel(
  ['file1', 'file2'].map(function(fname) {
    return function(done) {
      fs.writeFile(fname, fdata, (err) => {
        done(err, customResults);
      });
    };
  }),
  // The callback when every function above is done
  function(err, results) {
    // `results` contains a collection of what you've passed
    // on the `done` callbacks above
  }
);
```

If you want the tasks to run one by one in order you would use [async.series](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.series). If you want the functions to pass its results to the next task, you can use [async.waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall). Of course, there are other functions you can use but the ones I mentioned are some pretty common ones.

Comment: Yes, you recommended an external library for no required reason. Promises solve this thing well and are built in. It's a well written answer I just don't believe it is useful given the current state of asynchronous actions in JS.

Comment: The OP didn't say he didn't want to use external library though.

Comment: Right, one just isn't required in this case. Introducing an external dependency where one is not needed seemed unnecessary to me. caolan/async was an important library a few years ago but now it is a thing of the past mostly. I think recommending it to new users is doing them disservice.

Comment: How can it be a thing of the past when the library is still being actively maintained?

Comment: It still ends up with a function call in the end, not continuing the code flow in the same scope. Just one callback instead of many.

Comment: @VadimFedorov: `writeFile` starts an asynchronous process, you *can't* continue the code flow in the same scope when handling its completion; my promises solution doesn't either. But with arrow functions and closures, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score -1):

use Async:

```
async.map([['name1', 'data1'], ['name2', 'data2'], ['name3', 'data3']], 
function (item, cb) {
     fs.writeFile(item[0], item[1], (err, res) => {
        callback(err, res);
    });
}, 
function(err, results) {
    // results is now an array of results
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I've experimented with Promises and I am not thoroughly convinced that there is much of an advantage to using them over doing something like this:

```
    let counter = 0;
    (some loop declaration) {
            // (preparing data etc)
            counter += 1;
            fs.writeFile(fname, fdata, (err) => {
                    counter -= 1;
                    if ( counter==0 ) done()
            });
    }

    function done(){
        // that's it 
    }
```

Very similar to your initial code, except instead of using setTimeout(), I check the value of counter as each operation completes.

IMO, this is just as effective and maybe easier to read.

Or, if you don't like having a separate function to finish up...

```
    let counter = 0;
    (some loop declaration) {
            // (preparing data etc)
            counter += 1;
            fs.writeFile(fname, fdata, (err) => {
                    counter -= 1;
                    if ( counter==0 ) {
                            // that's it, finish up
                    }
            });
    }
```

Comment: I still end up with a function call in the end, not continuing the code flow in the same scope.

Comment: @Vadim, sure, but it doesn't have to be a separate function. I added an alternative. In fact, done() is practically the same as Promise.all(ops).then() except without having to manage the promise objects.